# Prevent reverse engineering SQL Server analysis services (SSAS) database

Tags: sql-server, database, ssas, reverse-engineering

Is there a way to prevent reverse engineering an SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Services) database?
As you know, anyone with permission to connect and browse the SSAS DB will be able to reverse engineer it using Visual Studio.

Comment: SSAS is not a type of database.

Comment: SSIS package, not SSAS package! I'm talking about Analysis services NOT integration services!!

Comment: If you don't trust the people that are connecting to your SSAS instance, perhaps they shouldn't have access...

Comment: A typical implementation workflow includes installing a SQL Server Analysis Services instance, creating a tabular or multidimensional data model, deploying the model as a database to a server instance, processing the database to load it with data, and then assigning permissions to allow data access. When ready to go, the data model can be accessed by any client application supporting Analysis Services as a data source.

Comment: So @JeffUK according to Microsoft it can be called a database!!

Comment: It actually is, but it is a very specific and specialized one.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.

The problem you have is that you think that there is anything hidden there - it is not. This is like asking "can I somehow hide from the driver how the car cockpit looks like".

The information VS uses is the same any client use to efficiently navigate and use the database. WIthout it, you could not do any analysis using... i.e. Excel.

Given that being sliced and diced and analyzed is the PURPOSE for the data, and one needs to know the structure for this.... there is simply no way to hide this knowledge.

If there is anything special you try to achieve - open another question, but given how LITTLE (extremely little) logic a SSAS cube contains... there is IMHO no way to hide it. See, this is like a SQL database - ONLY the tables, no triggers etc. - you could not hide that and expect clients to still provide full experience. They need to know what data is where.